# How to hide table rows that fetch the info from a database based on string given and when a button is pressed

Tags: php, html

An HTML table is given in which there are people (agents in this case) who have the following information displayed Id, Name, Rank, Location, and **Status**. Status can have 3 values. Online, Offline, Disconnected. Based on the status that one of the agents has I want to put 3 buttons as such Online, Offline, and Disconnected, and when a button is pressed to hide the other rows with different values. For example, if I press Online, table rows on the HTML side that contain the status Offline and Disconnected disappear, this goes for the others too the other way around. I have no idea to achieve what I said earlier and I am open to any solution that is deemed to resolve my problem.

```
<table id="main_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Agent Name</td>
        <td>Agent Rank</td>
        <td>Agent Location</td>
        <td>Status</td>
      </tr>

      <?php

      require 'CMS/processing/conn.php';

      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM agents");

      while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $info['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentRank']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['locationNames']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentStatus']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to do this immediately instead of by submitting a form, you need to do it in JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: I have tried with JS in a manner that I have a select list and I store the option into localStorage so the selected value doesn't go away upon page refresh and also managed to play around with the selected value but the problem is not about hiding a pre-defined row to say so but a string which resides inside a row. I am open to any advice on how to tackle this problem .

Comment: There are many questions about filtering table rows based on matching a search string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below logic : Create 3 buttons with `<a>` and pass status value as GET to the same page then while fetching check whether it has GET or not

Note:This is not a answer :passing direct GET value to sql query may cause some security issues

```
<a href="?status=1" class="btn">Online</a>//put the status value based on your status
<a href="?status=2" class="btn">Offline</a>//put the status value based on your status
<a href="?status=3" class="btn">Disconnected</a>//put the status value based on your status

<table id="main_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Agent Name</td>
        <td>Agent Rank</td>
        <td>Agent Location</td>
        <td>Status</td>
      </tr>

      <?php

      require 'CMS/processing/conn.php';
    if(isset($_GET['status']))
    {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM agents where agentStatus='".$_GET['status']."'");
    }
    else
    {
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM agents");
    }
      while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $info['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentRank']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['locationNames']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['agentStatus']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use javascript within a  tag or jQuery since this sounds like you need dynamic functionality on a static webpage.

For your button pass in the name of the function you're creating inside your  tag

```
<button onclick="yourFunctionName(yourString)"></button>
```

Inside your  tag have the function accept the yourString paramater

```
function yourFunctionName(yourString){
  if(yourString === "whatever"){
  $('tbody tr').hide()   
  $('tbody tr').show()
 }
```

etc! Let me know if you need any more clarification on anything

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Since I have seen I can do it with PHP I went with it right away. I will keep in mind of this solution in other project . Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Output echo an attribute on each row `<tr data-status="online">` etc.
Then in script use `document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-status='online']` to find all rows with that status, loop thru the array and toggle each row style.display to 'table-row' or 'none' as required.

You could also do the same using CSS by assigning a class `<tr class="online">` etc. Then in script dynamically altering the CSS definition of that class, changing the display to 'table-row' or 'none' as required.